# Question 3a from Exercises 3.3.2 from F. Mary Hart - Guide to Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

The question asks whether $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{3^n+5^n}{4^n+7^n}$ converges. The hints tell me it does converge and that is done using the ratio test. After writing $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ out I get 
 $\frac{3^{n+1}+5^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}+7^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{4^n+7^n}{3^n+5^n}$.
 Where should I go from here? I could not manage to cancel out any terms.

Comment: I think instead of the ratio test, the following is easier: $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{3^n+5^n}{4^n+7^n} \le \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{5^n+5^n}{7^n} = 2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^n = 2\left(\frac{1}{1-5/7}-1\right) = 5 < \infty$$

Comment: @DanielP Thanks that makes more sense to me and an easier way to do it.

Comment: Even easier (but, like Daniel's comment and unlike the duplicate, not answering your precise question): $\frac{3^n+5^n}{4^n+7^n}\sim\left(\frac57\right)^n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval What does ~ mean? Sorry I am unfamiliar with that notation

Comment: It is extremely useful in the study of sequences and series. If $v_n$ is never $0,$ [$u_n\sim v_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) means $u_n/v_n\to1.$ (There is a more general definition which allows $v_n$ to be sometimes $0$, but seldom useful.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks that makes sense. But what would I be able to do with that information?

Comment: Assume $v_n>0.$ If $u_n\sim v_n$ (or equivalently $v_n\sim u_n$) then $u_n=O(v_n)$ hence if moreover $\sum v_n$ converges, then $\sum u_n$ converges (or equivalently: if moreover $\sum u_n$ diverges then $\sum v_n$ diverges).

Comment: @AnneBauval that makes sense. So we are just comparing $u_n$ to a sequence/series we know the behavior of? And what does the notation $O(v_n)$ mean?

Comment: Exactly. And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation